# How to fix metadata-generation-failed error when installing pytokenizations

Tags: pip

Returning this error in Colab:

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting pytokenizations==0.8.4
Using cached pytokenizations-0.8.4.tar.gz (3.8 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Tried upgrading pip and installing earlier versions with same error

Comment: Is it the complete error message?